# angular 2 material card

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

Hi I'm very new to web development and starting off directly with angular2... Im doing some dummy web page for learning purpose but unable to implement md-card..

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NewComponent} from './new.component';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
    imports:[BrowserModule,HttpModule,MaterialModule.forRoot()],
    providers:[],
    declarations:[AppComponent,NewComponent],
    bootstrap:[AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

in Html

```
    <div *ngFor="let data of dataServer" > 
    <div id="myimages">
<md-card>
<img src="{{data.images.image3}}">
</md-card>
    </div>  
    </div>
```

but ends up in following error

```
Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/@angular/material
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:647:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:37)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:304:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/@angular/material as "@angular/material" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
```

I'm not sure if i'm doing it right way.. Can somebody please provide with implementation or workaround of md-card using angualr2 typescript. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you included the reference to the @angular-material module in `system-config.ts` ?

Comment: @KunalSharma there is no such file in my project folder.. what i did was i installed angular material using npm via command prompt... PS: I do have a file named systemjs.config.js

Comment: How are you compiling typescript to Javascript then?

Comment: Im using visual studio code... npm start from command prompt does it for me.... the oly files im touching for now is app.module.ts and and the component.ts files.. sorry if i sound stupid.. im very new to this...

Comment: I guess you are missing few basic steps of setting up angular 2 projects. You can use `angular-cli` to generate boilerplate code for your application. [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/)

Comment: But the basic app is working... Im able to make api calls render data and populate view also... U still think i need to setup few more things ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124717/discussion-between-kunal-sharma-and-moulesh).

Answer (score 0):

I'm building an app with Angular 2 Material [Material card app](https://github.com/cuongnm265/small_essay) with angular-cli

Note: Material card is in localhost:4200/news and if it require to login, just pass user: `admin@admin.com` and password: `adm9`